# how to get all asp hidden field control id by jquery find function?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing an web application in `ASP.Net` using `C#`. In my code there is an aspx page and the associated `JQuery` code in a separate `js file` In my aspx page I have code sample is as follows

```
<div id="areaHiddenField">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESFullName" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESTitle" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESPhoneNumber" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESOfficePhoneNumber" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESMailID" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESWebsite" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESAddress1" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESAddress2" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESDisclaimer" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESPhoto" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESLogo" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESDesignation1" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESDesignation2" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Now I want to perform some operation for all hidden field. In separate .js file I am using following code

```
$("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="hf"]').each(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

But i didn't get any response from the code. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("#areaHiddenField").find("input[type='hidden']").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**OR**

If you want your same code to be functional, add `ClientIdMode = "static"` to all `HiddenFields`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#areaHiddenField input[type='hidden']").each(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

or

```
$("#areaHiddenField").find('input[id^=hf]').each(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

if your hidden elements are direct children element then better using `children()`

```
$("#areaHiddenField").children('input[id^=hs]').each(function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using this code to get all the ID of all hidden field of the said div but it is coming with content pace holder. $("#areaHiddenField input[type='hidden']").each(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }); So, how can I get only id of all hiddenfield not the content place holder and all.

Comment: Do you mean:
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function () {
    alert("hi");
});

Comment: Using this code $("#areaHiddenField input[type='hidden']").each(function () { alert($(this).attr("id")); });

Answer (score 0):

Just add **$(document).ready(function ()**  above your script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#areaHiddenField").find("[id^='hf']").each(function () {
       alert("hi");
    });
 });
```

it will work , I think you miss it otherwise it should work because not any problem in your script.

Comment: do you have master page in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

may be hidden field id is changing because it is server side and its not starting from hf..if you have master page then its start from ct100 so check the hidden field id from which word its start...i checked in my page having with master page its working perfectly...

```
<div id="areaHiddenField">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESFullName" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESTitle" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESPhoneNumber" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESOfficePhoneNumber" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESMailID" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESWebsite" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESAddress1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESAddress2" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESDisclaimer" runat="server" />

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESPhoto" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESLogo" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESDesignation1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfESDesignation2" runat="server" />
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#areaHiddenField").find('[ID^="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_"]').each(function () {debugger
var controlName = $(this).attr("ID");
var get_id=controlName.replace("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_","");
alert(get_id);
var set_val=document.getElementById(""+ controlName +"");
if(get_id=="hfESFullName")
{
set_val.value="xyz";
}
else if(get_id=="hfESTitle")
{
set_val.value="abc";
}
```

Comment: I am using this code $("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="ctl00_"]').each(function () {
        var controlName = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(controlName);
    }); Here it is showing ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_hiddenfieldid. I want only the hidden field id of the current page. How can I do that?

Comment: $("#areaHiddenField").find('[ID^="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_"]').each(function () {
   var controlName = $(this).attr("ID");
    var get_id=controlName.replace("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_","");
    
    alert(get_id); 
    });

Comment: from this code you can get specific id...@ShubhadeepChat

Comment: I want to assign some value to each hidden field from separate .js file. How can I do that? As your code now i can get the actual id of each hidden field now the task is to assign some value to them. Please help.

Comment: what type of value you want to assign and also you can assign different value for hidden field statically. so why you want to do this like and what you want to do with that code.? @ShubhadeepChat

Comment: Actually In my aspx page i have to create the hidden field control dynamically because I dont know that how much hiddenfield will be added to the page. It is completely coming from the database. Now after adding all hiddenfield there is an JQuery function in the .js file. I have to assign the value of that function to all the hidden field. Hope you will understand my application scenario. How can I do that?

Comment: you want to assign same value to all hidden field or value is different for all hidden field.?@ShubhadeepChat

Comment: Value is different for each hidden field. Actually The JQuery function will take parameters. Parameter of the function will be different.The code is like following. I want to do it dynamically.

Comment: $("#<%=hfESFullName.ClientID%>").val(gen_es_text("lblName", "lbltextName"));
$("#<%=hfESTitle.ClientID%>").val(gen_es_text("lblTitle", "lbltextTitle"));
$("#<%=hfESPhoneNumber.ClientID%>").val(gen_es_text("lblPhone", "lbltextPhone"));
$("#<%=hfESOfficePhoneNumber.ClientID%>").val(gen_es_text("lblOfficePhone", "lbltextOfficePhone"));
$("#<%=hfESMailID.ClientID%>").val(gen_es_text("lblMailID", "lbltextMailID"));
$("#<%=hfESWebsite.ClientID%>").val(gen_es_text("lblWebsite", "lbltextWebsite"));

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have restructured my code according to your suggestion but i am not getting proper result. Please check the following code

Comment: $("#areaHiddenField").find('[id^="ctl00_"]').each(function () {
        var controlName = $(this).attr("id");
        var actualID = controlName.replace("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_", "");
        var attr_val = document.getElementById("" + actualID + "");
        divID = "lbl" + actualID.slice(4, actualID.length);
        labelID = "lbltext" + actualID.slice(4, actualID.length);
        attr_val.value = gen_es_text(divID, labelID);
        alert(attr_val.value);
});

Comment: you want to assign hidden field value so i updated my code according to that.so in your code i m getting error gen_es_text is not defined. so post full code with declaration of variable.so i could better understand.@ShubhadeepChat

Comment: function gen_es_text(divID, lblID) { return labelID.html() + " " + divID.html()}

Comment: Can you send your mail id so that i can send you the code.

Comment: i can give you my id but i m accessing SO from company and i cant access my mail id in company.i would suggest you do it yourself.the problem will be solved soon and if you have any problem then you can ask another question on stackoverflow.if you get your answer of what you asked then don't forget this answer mark as answer..@ShubhadeepChat